# The number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 7985 and input n_features is 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, email-spam

I built a spam classifier with random forest and wanted to make a separate function that can classify  a text message  to be spam or ham and I tried:

```
def predict_message(pred_text):
    pred_text=[pred_text]
    pred_text2 = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(pred_text)
    pred_features = pd.DataFrame(pred_text2.toarray())
    prediction = rf_model.predict(pred_features)
    return (prediction)

pred_text = "how are you doing today?"

prediction = predict_message(pred_text)
print(prediction)
```

but it gives me the error:

```
The number of features of the model must match the input.
Model n_features is 7985 and input n_features is 1
```

I can't see the problem, how can I make it work?

Comment: Why did you re-ask this same question on the [meta] meta site? You've already got an answer here, one that you apparently have completely and rudely ignored before re-asking your question. Not good.

Comment: I have just started using the website and in my process of understanding. The unnecessary criticism of yours is rude, not my move. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Please read the [help] link and go through the [tour] to learn how to best use this site. I say this for your own benefit since if more of your questions on this site are poorly received, you could be banned from asking, something that you'll want to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `tfidf_vect.fit_transform(pred_text)` your vectorizer loses any information it had from your original training corpus.

**You should just call `transform`.**

These changes below should help:

```
def predict_message(pred_text):
    pred_text=[pred_text]
    pred_text2 = tfidf_vect.transform(pred_text)  # Changed
    prediction = rf_model.predict(pred_text2)
    return (prediction)

pred_text = "how are you doing today?"

prediction = predict_message(pred_text)
print(prediction)
```

Comment: @IşılBerfinKoparan: good, you finally acknowledged the answer